# Rearrange pandas personality dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in my code:

```
uid                                A    O    N    C    E
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   5    2    3    3    6
77c7d756a093150d4377720abeaeef76   1    2    1    3    4
b7e8a92987a530cc368719a0e60e26a3   6    4    4    1    3
...                                ...  ...  ...  ... ...
030001ac2145a938b07e686a35a2d638   5    5    3    4    2
```

and I would like to transform it to look like this:

```
uid                                trait    rating
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   A        5    
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   O        2
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   N        3
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   C        3
8e7cebf9a234c064b75016249f2ac65e   E        6
...                                ...  ...
```

I know that this will use a combination of transpose and some other pandas features, but I've had a good look at the documentation and I can't combine the examples in a way that makes sense (I'm still quite new to pandas). Let me know if I can provide more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
result=df.melt(id_vars='uid',var_name='trait',value_name='rating')
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output